# Cannot read property 'top' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning, traversal

I'm console.logging the `offset()` of an element and I get

```
left: 1236
top: 139
__proto__: Object
```

But when I log `offset().top` I get the error

`Cannot read property 'top' of null`

Here's my code in its entirety:

`console.log(('.index-title').eq(n).prev().offset().top);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n's 0, then you're at the start of the list and .prev() has nowhere to go, returning null instead of what would have been the "previous" object in the list.